# cmake parse arguments incorrectly in add_custom_target command

Tags: cmake

I wrote a cmake command like this:

```
add_custom_target(testar
              COMMAND clearmake -C gnu ${CMD_ARGS})
```

the `CMD_ARGS` is defined on the command line like:

```
cmake -DCMD_ARGS="-d -w"
```

But in the generated makefile, the `-d -w` is changed into `-d\ -w`; it added a slash before all spaces, resulting in:

```
clearmake -C gnu -d\ -w
```

If I use `VERBATIM` option in `add_custom_target`, cmake doesn't add a slash, but it quotes the argument like

```
clearmake -C gnu "-d -w"
```

which is incorrect, I would like:

```
clearmake -C gnu -d -w
```

What is the syntax needed to generate the above target?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arguments are expected to be a `list`, which "-d -w" is not (it's just a string). You can do two things:

1. Pass in the arguments as -DCMD_ARGS="-d;-w" (the space is a semicolon)
2. Use the [separate_arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/separate_arguments.html) command on `CMD_ARGS` before you pass it into `add_custom_target` (which makes spaces semi-colons to generate a proper `list`).

Nothing in the `add_custom_target` command needs to change, the input to CMake is incorrect which can be fixed with 1 or handled by 2.

Comment: @tpg2114 I don't understand why the first few things in the `COMMAND` don't need to be separated by a semicolon? It is `COMMAND clearmake -C gnu ${CMD_ARGS}`, but why not `COMMAND clearmake;-C;gnu;${CMD_ARGS}` ?