# make to cmake porting question: re-directing shell script output to a compiler in a recipe

Tags: cmake, makefile

I am trying to port a number of project makefiles to cmake. Currently I am stuck trying to model the behavior of the snippet of the makefile shown below.

(partial original makefile)

```
all:            ../libc.a

../libc.a:      ../ar ../ranlib $(OBJS)
                ../ar rc $@ $(OBJS)
                ../ranlib $@

$(OBJS):     $(LIBCDIR)/mips/sys/SYS.h
                @echo creating $*.o
                @printf '#include "SYS.h"\nSYS($*)\n' | $(CMAKE_C_COMPILER) $(CMAKE_C_FLAGS) - -c -o $*.o
```

This is part of the build system for retrobsd in case you're wondering where it comes from. It builds fine under make.

I have tried various invocations of "add_custom_target" but none work. Analyzing the build output seems to indicate that there are issues in the way text gets quoted in the resulting makefile created by cmake.

Below is one of the variations of the CMakeLists.txt file tried

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(myRetroBSD_native_libc LANGUAGES C)

set(OBJ_FILES
__sysctl
accept
)

set(OBJECT_OUTPUT_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/objs)

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${OBJECT_OUTPUT_DIR})

foreach(OBJ_FILE ${OBJ_FILES})

    file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${OBJECT_OUTPUT_DIR}/${OBJ_FILE}.sh CONTENT "printf '#include \"SYS.h\"\nSYS(${OBJ_FILE})\n'")
    
    add_custom_target(
        ${OBJ_FILE} ALL
        COMMAND bash "${OBJECT_OUTPUT_DIR}/${OBJ_FILE}.sh | ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} - -c -o ${OBJECT_OUTPUT_DIR}/${OBJ_FILE}.o "
        VERBATIM
    )

endforeach()
```

I've tried with and without the "VERBATIM" flag set. Neither case works.

**Update**
The definition of the compiler and the flags used is as shown below.

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/local/mips-2013.11/bin/mips-sde-elf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-mips32r2 -EL -msoft-float -nostdinc -fshort-double -Os -I${TOPSRC}/include -x assembler-with-cpp -c -B${TOPSRC}/lib/")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -I${TOPSRC}/src/libc/mips/sys -I/usr/local/mips-2013.11/mips-sde-elf/include/sys -DLWHI=lwr -DLWLO=lwl -DSWHI=swr -DSWLO=swl")
```

The following snippets show the make targets that cmake creates.

VERBATIM flag **NOT** set:

```
CMakeFiles/__sysctl:
    bash __sysctl.sh | /usr/local/mips-2013.11/bin/mips-sde-elf-gcc "-mips32r2 -EL -msoft-float -nostdinc -fshort-double -Os -I/retrobsd/include -x assembler-with-cpp -c -B /retrobsd/lib/ -I/retrobsd/src/libc/mips/sys -I/usr/local/mips-2013.11/mips-sde-elf/include/sys -DLWHI=lwr -DLWLO=lwl -DSWHI=swr -DSWLO=swl" - -c -o retrobsd_native_libc-build/objs/__sysctl.o
```

VERBATIM flag set:

```
CMakeFiles/__sysctl:
    bash __sysctl.sh | /usr/local/mips-2013.11/bin/mips-sde-elf-gcc -mips32r2\ -EL\ -msoft-float\ -nostdinc\ -fshort-double\ -Os\ -I/myretrobsd/include\ -x\ assembler-with-cpp\ -c\ -B/myretrobsd/lib/\ -I/myretrobsd/src/libc/mips/sys\ -I/usr/local/mips-2013.11/mips-sde-elf/include/sys\ -DLWHI=lwr\ -DLWLO=lwl\ -DSWHI=swr\ -DSWL=swl - -c -o retrobsd_native_libc-build/objs/__sysctl.o
```

In both cases I get the following error:

```
mips-sde-elf-gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option '-mips32r2 -EL -msoft-float -nostdinc -fshort-double -Os -I/home/gartnerd/code/myretrobsd/include -x assembler-with-cpp -c -B/home/gartnerd/code/myretrobsd/lib/ -I/home/gartnerd/code/myretrobsd/src/libc/mips/sys -I/usr/local/mips-2013.11/mips-sde-elf/include/sys -DLWHI=lwr -DLWLO=lwl -DSWHI=swr -DSWLO=swl'
mips-sde-elf-gcc: note: valid arguments to '-mips' are: 1 2 3 32 32r2 4 64 64r2
```

The quotes and the backslash characters in the makefile recipe appear to be the culprits preventing the successful creation of an object file

**Update 2**

I would suggest that the duplicate question mentioned isn't quite the same. I'm not passing any cmake variables via the command line.

However, as mentioned it is similar and I did find a solution. It is to remove the quotes used in the following:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS -mips32r2 -EL -msoft-float -nostdinc -fshort-double -Os -I${TOPSRC}/include -x assembler-with-cpp -c -B${TOPSRC}/lib/)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -I${TOPSRC}/src/libc/mips/sys -I/usr/local/mips-2013.11/mips-sde-elf/include/sys -DLWHI=lwr -DLWLO=lwl -DSWHI=swr -DSWLO=swl)
```

and in the following line in the add_custom_target function

```
COMMAND bash ${OBJECT_OUTPUT_DIR}/${OBJ_FILE}.sh | ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} - -c -o ${OBJECT_OUTPUT_DIR}/${OBJ_FILE}.o
```

It seems obvious now, but it's not clear when quotes should/need to be used.

Comment: I don't know my `make` expansions very well, so can you provide an example of what that last command would expand to?  And you probably just need to generate the file, not add custom targets/commands.

Comment: The makefile is feeding the generated content into the assembler.  Your CMake code is feeding it into the C compiler.  There may be other relevant differences, but that one seems significant enough to me.

Comment: "Analyzing the build output seems to indicate that there are issues in the way text gets quoted in the resulting makefile created by cmake." - Yes, passing some special characters to `add_custom_target` requires **escaping**. Which **exact character** from your `add_custom_target` call is transformed incorrectly into the resulted Makefile? Have you tried to escape that character?

Comment: @JohnBollinger - I've updated the code to show the equivalent assembler and assembler flags.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - I don't think that escaping the quotes or backslash character will help. Their removal from the string produced would be better :)

Comment: When pass to the `add_custom_target` a variable which contains several arguments, the variable should be a **list**, where arguments are separated with semicolon. While variable `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` describes several compiler flags, the variable itself is a **string**, not a **list**. So, the content of the variable should be processed via `separate_arguments` for being able to be used in custom target. This approach is described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9080554/3440745).

Comment: BTW, in your CMake code you show **double quotes** around all parameters after `bash`. But it seems that you don't have these quotes in the code which you are **actually run**. By CMake rules, the whole quotation should produce a **single argument**. But in your generated Makefile you have that quotation splitted into separate arguments. When ask a question on Stack Overflow make sure that you post the code which is actually tried.